# Multiple 2D Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

Assuming that we have a 2D array of unspecified dimension, I want to create a method that will generate multiple of the array, such that this method:

> tile(int[][] list, int row, int column) {
>   ...
>   }

will give me that array expanded horizontally by int column, and expanded vertically by int row.

How can you go about this? My attempt was:

```
public static int[][] tile(int[][] list, int row, int column) {
    int [][] renewed = new int[row*(list.length)][column*(list[0].length)];

        for (int i = 0; i<list.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<renewed.length; j+=row) {
           renewed[j] =list[i];
        }
    }
```

But I had no luck whatsoever in getting the result I wanted. It appears that doing it this way requires 3~4 nested for loop to account for every possibility, and gets out of hand instantly. Can anyone give me a clue?

Comment: Any reason this is tagged JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int [][] list={{12,3},{4,6}};
    //loop through each array in the 2d array
    for(int x=0;x<list.length;x++){

            //make copy of array
            int[] listcopy=list[x].clone();
            //expand length of array by one
                    list[x]=new int [listcopy.length+1];
                    list[x][list.length-1]=0;
            for(int p=0;p<listcopy.length;p++){
                //copy each index to new array
                list[x][p]=listcopy[p];
            }

    }
    //make copy of 2d array
    int[][] listcopy=list.clone();
    //expand length of 2d array by 1
    list=new int[listcopy.length+1][];
    list[list.length-1]=new int[1];
    //assign values to the 2d array
    for(int x=0;x<listcopy.length;x++){
        list[x]=listcopy[x];
    }
```

It sets the value of the new array index to be 0.

Comment: Why are you doing list copy.length+1? and then setting list[x][list.length-1] to 0?

Comment: To expand the array, I thought that that was what the question meant. Also if you expand the array and don't set a value to the new index, you may get a null pointer exception.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. By expansion I meant if initial array is {12,3}{4,6}, and row is 2 and column is 3, the method would produce {12,3,12,3,12,3}{4,6,4,6,4,6}{12,3,12,3,12,3}{4,6,4,6,4,6}.

Comment: um.. shouldn't there only be {12,3,12,3,12,3}{4,6,4,6,4,6} as there are only 2 rows?